# How do I get bullets to move in the direction of the mouse's position?

Tags: xna, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shoot a bullet towards cursor - top down 2d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/shoot-a-bullet-towards-cursor-top-down-2d)

I'm creating a 2D top down shooter, and I want to get the bullets to go in the direction of the mouse. Not sure of the logic that goes into it.

Comment: This is a very common question. I can't imagine you searched the site first. Please do so in the future before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use trigonometry like here: [2D Magnet-like repelling behavior](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37822/2d-magnet-like-repelling-behavior/37825#37825)

But the very simplest approach is:

```
//init:
CONSTANT_FACTOR = .001;


//every frame:
dx = mouse.x - bullet.x;
dy = mouse.y - bullet.y;

bullet.vx = dx * CONSTANT_FACTOR;
bullet.vy = dy * CONSTANT_FACTOR;

bullet.x += bullet.vx;
bullet.y += bullet.vy;
```